# Is it a bad practice to call exit() inside a parallel region in OpenMP?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a program using both MPI and OpenMP.

The master spawns several slaves.
Each slave is multithreaded with OpenMP and one thread is dedicated to communications (MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED).

When the communication thread receives a message from the master indicating that the process has to stop I don't want to wait for all threads inside the parallel region to finish.

So for now I call the exit() function inside the parallel region but I'm wondering if it's a bad practice and if there is a more elegant way to exit a process inside a parallel region ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe from OS' point of view. OS closes all handles, terminates threads and frees all associated memory when you exit a process. Modern operating systems have to do that because processes can exit inadvertently and that must not affect the system stability.

But from your app's point of view it all depends. Can your app exit in a dirty state? If you miss a disk write would it corrupt your data files? If you don't send a packet would be transaction clean, would everything still keep in sync? It's all up to what your app is doing.

Answer (score 2):

## Summary

This is **valid OpenMP** but **incorrect MPI**.

## OpenMP

From page 3 of OpenMP 4.0:

> For C/C++, an executable statement, possibly compound, with a single
>   entry at the top and a single exit at the bottom, or an OpenMP
>   construct.
>
> ...
>
> Calls to exit() are allowed in a structured block.

## MPI

From page 357 of MPI 3.1 (definition of `MPI_Finalize`):

> This routine cleans up all MPI state. If an MPI program terminates normally (i.e., not due to a call to MPI_ABORT or an unrecoverable error) then each process must call MPI_FINALIZE before it exits.

## Practical consequencies

In practice, there are usually minimal adverse consequences to violating this part of the MPI standard.  However, it is possible that not calling `MPI_Finalize` will cause resource leaks in some implementations, which may eventually accumulate to make nodes in your system unusable until they are rebooted.

Because `MPI_Finalize` is collective, it cannot be used like `exit`, although you can - in theory - use `MPI_Abort` to exit locally.  However, this may tear down the entire MPI environment, since many implementations are not rigorous about localizing failures, even if `MPI_Abort` is called as `MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_SELF,0)`.